# Priority Queues(heaps) implementation for parallel processing

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, binary-heap

Given "n" threads and "m" jobs of varying time taken to complete. If there is a free thread, it immediately takes the next job from the list. If a thread has started processing a job, it doesn’t interrupt or stop until it finishes processing the job. If several threads try to take jobs from the list simultaneously, the thread with a smaller index takes the job.

Determine for each job which thread will process it and when will it start processing.

Input :

```
2 5 # n m
1 2 3 4 5 #  integers  — the times in seconds it takes any thread to process the -the job.
```

Output :

```
0 0  # worker starting_time
1 0
0 1
1 2
0 4
```

My code :

```
from collections import namedtuple

AssignedJob = namedtuple("AssignedJob", ["worker", "started_at"])

def heapify(arr, i=0):# MIN HEAP

  #  0 --> time, 1 --> worker

  smallest = i
  l = 2*i + 1 # left child of node i
  r = 2*i + 2 # right child of node i

  if l < len(arr)  and arr[l][0] < arr[smallest][0]:
    smallest = l

  if r < len(arr)  and arr[r][0] < arr[smallest][0]:
    smallest = r
  
  if smallest != i:

    arr[i], arr[smallest] = arr[smallest], arr[i]
    heapify(arr, smallest)

  return arr[0][1] # worker whose time is lowest (top of min-heap)


def assign_jobs(n_workers, jobs):

    result = []
    next_free_time = [0] * n_workers

    for job in jobs:

        zip_time_workers = list(zip(next_free_time, [i for i in range(n_workers)]))
        #list of tuples --> (time, worker)

        next_worker = heapify(zip_time_workers)
        # get worker with highest priority

        result.append(AssignedJob(next_worker, next_free_time[next_worker]))
        next_free_time[next_worker] += job

    return result


def main():
    n_workers, n_jobs = map(int, input().split())
    jobs = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(jobs) == n_jobs

    assigned_jobs = assign_jobs(n_workers, jobs)

    for job in assigned_jobs:
        print(job.worker, job.started_at)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It passes the sample case mentioned above but fails on others.

Failing Test case input :

```
4 20
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Expected Output:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 1
0 2
1 2
2 2
3 2
0 3
1 3
2 3
3 3
0 4
1 4
2 4
3 4
```

What am I doing wrong? a better implementation is also welcomed, thanks!

EDIT: cannot use python's pre-defined functions for priority queues (need underlying logic/approach)

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything to ensure ties are broken the way they're supposed to be broken.

Comment: Your `heapify` isn't a heapify either, and performing a full re-heapify on every iteration would be really slow even if you had a working heapify.

Comment: I see, if I heapify from the last non-leaf node (len(arr)//2 -1), I am even getting even worse output.

Comment: (Well, it's a heapify under the definition of "heapify" used in some sources, though not the definition used by Python's `heapq` standard library module. It's still not going to be enough to restore the heap invariant the way you're using it.)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I cannot use ```heapq``` as need core logic, edited.

Comment: @hack3r_0m I see this question was asked 6 months ago, hopefully you have solved it by now.  Please consider posting your answer here to your own question, otherwise maybe consider removing the question as it is currently a dead-end.